# How to do a LIKE search with another table's values?

Tags: join, sql-server-2012

I want to do a LIKE search on two tables. One table has a column of search terms and the other table has the column in which to perform the LIKE searches. Here are the tables:

```
create table #TableA
(
    UserName Varchar(50)
)
create table #TableB
(
    Department Varchar(50),
    Keyword Varchar(50)
)
Insert Into #TableA VALUES('bob_sales') 
Insert Into #TableA VALUES('mary_accounting')
Insert Into #TableA VALUES('sammi_accountant')
Insert Into #TableA VALUES('fred_bestSellerEver123')

Insert Into #TableB VALUES('Accounting', 'accounting') 
Insert Into #TableB VALUES('Accounting', 'accountant')
Insert Into #TableB VALUES('Sales', 'sales')
Insert Into #TableB VALUES('Sales', 'seller')
```

I'd like to run a query that uses **LIKE %keyword%** and gives me:

```
bob_sales              | Sales
mary_accounting        | Accounting
sammi_accountant       | Accounting
fred_bestSellerEver123 | Sales
```

Comment: Is it some sort of **Data Cleansing?**

Comment: It's for being able to categorize lots of data based on keyword terms that relate the data to individual departments

Answer (score 1):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/76b32/3/0)**

```
SELECT
   ta.UserName
   ,tb.Department
FROM TableA ta
JOIN TableB tb
  ON  ta.UserName LIKE '%' + tb.[keyword] + '%' 
 /* If needed  add COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS */
```

**Remarks:**

If your data can contains something like: `sammi_accountant_accounting` you should add `DISTINCT` to `SELECT` statement to avoid duplicates.

For `bob_sales_accounting` bob will appear twice because it belongs to 2 groups.

Comment: ok, wow. I didn't realize that you could JOIN on that? I always assumed that a JOIN must be done on two columns of the same data. Very cool, thank you. Any idea on why this appears to be case sensitive when all of my other uses of LIKE % % in my database are not case sensitive? Because of TEMP tables maybe?

Comment: Case sensitive depends on used collation, your tempdb can have different that database you work with, you can add `COLLATE ... case_insensitve`

Comment: @FujiBob Check this `SELECT name, collation_name 
FROM sys.databases` and compare tempdb with your db.Use COLLATION which is case insensitive and it works with your language

Comment: All are the same:

collation_name
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

I can dig into it later I suppose. I don't want to take the conversation too far away from the post in which you have already solved! Thank you kindly! :)

Comment: @FujiBob Great, happy I can help :)

Comment: @FujiBob Just in case you can add `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` if there will be `sammi_accountant_accounting` record that can match many times

Comment: Good point. I have updated my query and tested it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Another method, without join, just for fun:

```
select department, 
(select top 1 username from #tablea a 
where a.username like '%' + b.keyword + '%') UserName
from #tableb b
```

Comment: Keep in mind that subquery in select can return more than 1 row and it will all fail

Comment: Great now with `TOP 1` you will get random result for rows like: `bob_sales _accounting`

Comment: Very true, added top 1 to address that. Great suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps, ideally we would not be using 'like' to join production tables. It may not be too late to add a reference table with keys to do a more traditional join.